# Missing 'man' entries after upgrade

Tags: macos, unix

Having upgraded from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion a few days ago, I find that most of the 'man' entries from section 3 (programming functions) are missing.  For example:

```
phillip-millss-macbook-pro:etc phil$ man fopen
No manual entry for fopen
```

Exploring with the terminal shows me that all that remains in man3 directories within the 'man' search path are things related to Perl.

Is there something extra that I should be installing to get the reference information back?

Comment: Have you installed Xcode or the command line tools package from its preferences or https://developer.apple.com/downloads/?

Comment: I have the new Xcode installed and working fine.  (I suppose it's possible **that's** what caused the 'man' problem.)  Even though the auxiliary tools description doesn't mention documentation, I'll try installing that from the link you provided.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can set an environmental variable called MANPATH that will tell the "man" command where to look for the man pages. I see my mac 10.12.6 (Sierra) does not have that variable set.  According to "man man"  output, it uses /etc/man.conf to know where the directories are. You can add missing paths into that file.  That file may be overwritten by an mac os x update, so you may have to do it again.  To find your missing man3 files, which are probably still on your disk, try "locate \*man3"  and it should list every directory with a man3 folder in it.
Boyd

Comment: Given the OPs last comment the issue is he has not got the manual pages installed